# Login with Facebook and Twitter using OpenId

Tags: facebook, twitter, webforms, openid, openid-provider

I am working on an application. this application uses openId(google and yahoo) for authentication. My question is that possible to use openid for facebook and twitter? if there is a possibility than how to implement it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sadly no, Facebook implements their own login protocol on top of OAuth2. Twitter also!.

Answer (score 0):

see this tutorial for facebook
http://claudio.cicali.name/post/2010/01/use-facebook-connect-in-your-application/

Comment: is this is helpful for you?!

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't fit with the question. He is not asking about "how to login with facebook".